# Need direct link to download Linux(Ubuntu 11.04) Operating System

Tags: 11.04, ubuntu-email-address

I need direct link to download Linux(Ubuntu 11.04) Operating System .It should be free version for evaluation purpose .

Comment: Any reason to prefer 11.04? It has reached end of life and will not be supported anymore.

Comment: okay. What is the latest version that i need to download?

Comment: The versions you can curently download are 12.04, 14.04, 16.04, and 16.10.

Comment: Technically, old versions are still [available for download](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/natty/), but **please** don't use end-of-life versions.

Comment: Right. Suggest me the best version to download and also share the link if possible. Thanks.

Comment: You can use LTS(Long term support)version like 14.04 16.04 which will be supported for 5 years.Now the current version is 16.10

Comment: And there is no such think as free for evaluation purposes in free as in freedom software. You can install Ubuntu and if you want buy support from canonical.

Comment: Current supported LTS versions are 12.04 (until April 2017), 14.04, and 16.04. 16.10 is not an LTS release. It is the most current release, but only carries 9 months of support, not 5 years.

Answer (score 1):

The latest version is Ubuntu 16.10. It may be downloaded for free here:
http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.10/

Comment: I'd add 16.04 as it is the latest LTS release, and maybe a link on how to install (as OP seems like he can't use AskUbuntu or even Google correctly if he thinks that he should use 11.04 and that Ubuntu is not free).